# Erlang : how to implement Erlang list comprehension ?

Tags: erlang, list-comprehension

Implement an Erlang list comprehension that takes two elements from a list and makes a new list of lists.

I have this code

```
pair([], Acc) -> lists:reverse(Acc);

pair(L, Acc0) -> 
    [ A, B | T ] = L,
    Acc = [ [A, B] | Acc0 ],
    pair(T, Acc).
```

which works fine:

```
7> l:pair(lists:seq(1,6), []).  
[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
```

but it seems like I should be able to implement this as a list comprehension. My Erlang-fu is too weak to come up with it.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

No, a list comprehension would not be a good way to do that, by definition they only work on one element a a time. In your code there is really no need to use an accumulator, the difference in speed is small, [here](http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/myths.html#id61381), and it becomes clearer without it. I think so at least.

```
pairs([A,B|L]) ->
    [[A,B]|pairs(L)];
pairs([]) -> [].
```

Comment: This follows the Erlang mantra "let it crash", e.g. for the case `[a]`.

Comment: @Tilman Yes, the function is **defined** to take pairs of elements so if it is an error if there is an odd number of elements in the list. You could of course always define what is to happen in that case and handle it after that.

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension will be clunky because it inevitably must do something for *every* element of the list. To create a list comprehension you must thus try to find out if it's an even or odd element you are talking to. Here's an idea of what I'm talking about:

```
pair(L) ->
    L2 = lists:zip(lists:seq(1, length(L)), L),
    [[A, B] || {Ai, A} <- L2, {Bi, B} <- L2,
          Ai rem 2 == 1, Bi rem 2 == 0, Ai + 1 == Bi].
```

The time complexity on this one is probably horrible because as far as I'm aware Erlang does not optimize this in any way.

I don't think there's anything wrong with your function and you should stick to it.